# Calculating Moran's I using R

Tags: r

I am trying to learn more about Moran's I (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran%27s_I).

I am working with the R programming language - I have the following shapefile of North Carolina (USA):

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(leafgl)
library(colourvalues)
library(leaflet.extras)


nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

leaflet(data = nc) %>% addPolygons( stroke = FALSE) %>% addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% addPolygons(data = nc, weight=1, popup = ~NAME,
                label = ~NAME, group = "name", col = 'blue') %>% 
    addSearchFeatures(targetGroups  = 'name', options = searchFeaturesOptions(zoom=10, openPopup=TRUE))
```

[image]

As a learning example, suppose each of these polygons has a number of hospitals:

```
library(sf)
library(spdep) 
library(spData) 
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
nc$hospitals <- sample(0:20, nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)

Simple feature collection with 100 features and 15 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
First 10 features:
    AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                           geom hospitals
1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1      10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...        14
2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0      10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...        18
3  0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5     208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...        13
4  0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1     123   830     2     145 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...         2
5  0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9    1066  1606     3    1197 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...         9
6  0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7     954  1838     5    1237 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...        17
7  0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0     115   350     2     139 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...        10
8  0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0     254   594     2     371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3...         4
9  0.118     1.421  1836    1836      Warren 37185  37185       93   968     4     748  1190     2     844 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3...        19
10 0.124     1.428  1837    1837      Stokes 37169  37169       85  1612     1     160  2038     5     176 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3...        13
```

I then tried to calculate Moran's I:

```
nb <- poly2nb(nc)
listw <- nb2listw(nb, style = "W")
moran.test(nc$hospitals, listw)
```

The code seems to have run and produced the following output:

```
Moran I test under randomisation

data:  nc$hospitals  
weights: listw    

Moran I statistic standard deviate = 0.97321, p-value = 0.1652
alternative hypothesis: greater
sample estimates:
Moran I statistic       Expectation          Variance 
      0.053703958      -0.010101010       0.004298263
```

Based on these results, it appears that there is no statistically significant autocorrelation and that hospitals are not spatially clustered and hospitals are not spatially autocorrelated.

Have I understood this correctly?